# sql query with select before insert

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am currently working on the following sql code which should insert a new data set only if it doesn't exist so far. The sql code works fine when being executed in phpmyadmin. If I execute the code within php I get the error (see below).

The sql code is the following:

```
INSERT INTO `historiclist` (`id`, `date`, `name`, `idnumber`, `prop1`, `prop2`, `prop3`, `difflimit1`, `difflimit2`)    
        SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
                            0                   as `id`, 
                            1515529465          as `date`, 
                            'johndoe'       as `name`, 
                            '381'           as `idnumber`, 
                            105         as `prop1`, 
                            240             as `prop2`, 
                            60          as `prop3`, 
                            '-10'   as `difflimit1`, 
                            '-10'   as `difflimit2`
                        ) AS tmp 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT `id` FROM historiclist  
                WHERE   `date`      = 1515529465
                    AND `name`  = 'johndoe'
                    AND `idnumber`      = '381'
        ) LIMIT 1;
```

The mysql error I receive is:

> Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO `historiclist` (`id`, `date`, `name`, `idnumber`, `prop1`, `prop' at line 21

The mysterious situation is also that prop2 is not fully displayed. So it cuts the 2 in the end of the name as well as e. g. prop3.

What am I missing?

//Edit I was missing something else as well ... here my php code:

```
$sql1return      = sqlQUERY($connection, $sql1);
$message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";

function sqlQUERY($connection, $sqlinput){
    $return     = @mysql_query($sqlinput, $connection);
    return $return;
}
```

The database connection works just fine in any other place (I know it is a bit outdated however).

Comment: You say you're running that in PHP, so where's your PHP code?

Comment: If the query works in phpMyAdmin, the error is likely in how you're handling the query in your PHP code.

Comment: "The mysterious situation is also that prop2 is not fully displayed." Nope, where MySQL had a problem is usually the start of the message; it just doesn't continue on from there forever. The fact the message begins with "INSERT " means it is taking issue with you even trying to insert, or "INSERT" is not actually the start of your query string.

Comment: the query definitely begins with insert. That's the whole query. Only missing part is the same sql code with different inputs. However, if I execute exactly the same sql code in phpmyadmin there is no error at all and it works perfectly.

Comment: please also show how you assign the string to `$sql1`, and give us a var_dump/echo of `$sql1` (or `$sqlinput`). _But_ why are you still running `mysql_*`?

Comment: You are still not showing all of your code.  Where are you actually assigning that query to a variable?

Comment: I think there's something else going on just before the INSERT

Comment: in $sql1 contains the sql code only. The sql code I posted in the beginning was the echo of $sql1.